# Hidden state in Flutter Applifecycle

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, offline, hidden

I am utilizing Firebase FCM to send push notifications in my Flutter app. How can a user receive offline notifications in Flutter? This implies that the user should be able to receive notifications even when offline (without using scheduled notifications for one or two days). Is this even possible? Is it possible in native development? I haven't found any way to achieve this functionality in Flutter.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the scenario of Offline notifications, please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to display push notifications offline in my Flutter app. I am sending notifications from Firebase, and I want users to receive notifications even when they are offline and don't have an internet connection. When I send a notification, I want them to be able to receive it, even if they are not connected to the internet